# How to deal with two variables with the same name in different js files?

Tags: javascript, variables, var

I have two javascript files with variables with same name, how can I define which one to use ?

Comment: You need to use a [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Comment: javascript variables are shared between files, this means if you use the same variable name in both files, it will be the same variable. To solve this you can either use a prefix or as Liam suggested use closure

Comment: Maybe you can try some [Namespacing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript)?!

Comment: you need to understand scopes like @rellyethan suggested

Answer (score 5):

In Javascript, you can't actually have 2 variables made with different goals and have the same name in the same `scope`.

Basically, there're 2 types of scope: `global` and `local`. Global scope is what you're facing making 2 variables with the same name in different files.

Once, that was a common issue and developers agreed to try making files with different scopes and use global scope only when it's necessary and inevitable.

So, the most common way to create a new scope (local) is to close your code in function. Functions in javascript create a new scope, which is inaccessible from the global, but you still can reach the global scope from the local one.

Also, there're 2 ways to keep your code modular (1 file = 1 module): either using [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) or [CommonJS](http://spinejs.com/docs/commonjs) modules.

More about scopes[here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: @Liam Well, I thought about deep explaining, but at this point I understand that guy needs some tutors, which are the best at w3schools for understanding. But I get your point, I will make better answers.

Comment: @Liam I'll try to edit the answer before it gets deleted

Comment: @Liam edited my answer to meet minimal requirements.

Comment: An example of scoping would be good. But well done for putting the effort in to correct it. A lot of people don't do this!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the following scenario:

```
<html>...

<script src="file1.js">var x = "pizza";</script> 
<script src="file2.js">var x = "cheese";</script>
<script src="file3.js">var x = "chocolate";</script>
```

Your shared variable will always be overwritten by the latest value it has been given, in this case "chocolate".

If you want to split them up, either use a prefix or consider changing the names since once they are loaded into the main file, they are in the same namespace.

```
console.log(x); // chocolate will be printed since it is the last value it was (re)defined as.
</html>
```

### EDIT:

If you want it to work, the simplest way would be to change the variables' names.

```
<script src="file1.js">var x = "pizza";</script> 
<script src="file2.js">var y = "cheese";</script>
<script src="file3.js">var z = "chocolate";</script>

console.log(x); //pizza
console.log(y); //cheese
console.log(z); //chocolate
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps? this appears to be an illustration of the problem, not a solution

Comment: I mentioned how he can solve the problem, I doubt there's a need to show how to change a variable's name. Added the solution, none the less. :)